# Modifying authentication popup

Tags: magento2, javascript, extend

I'm trying to apply the authentication popup on a custom button in my module. I've implemented it by overriding it in my `requirejs-config`.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup': 'Vendor_CustomPopup/js/model/authentication-popup-download'
        }
    }
};
```

and my modified JS looks like this:

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function ($, modal) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            modalWindow: null,

            // Create popUp window for provided element
            createPopUp: function (element) {
                this.modalWindow = element;
                var options = {
                    'type': 'popup',
                    'modalClass': 'popup-authentication',
                    'responsive': true,
                    'innerScroll': true,
                    'trigger': '.download-purchase', // only change needed
                    'buttons': []
                };
                //console.log(options);
                modal(options, $(this.modalWindow));
            },

            // Show login popup window
            showModal: function () {
                $(this.modalWindow).modal('openModal');
            }
        }
    }
);
```

The only change I need to apply is the trigger in the options, this works, but is there a better way of modifying this without overriding the whole function?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a mixin and only update the function **createPopUp**.

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Customer/js/view/authentication-popup': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/authentication-popup-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/authentication-popup-mixin.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function (Component, $, modal) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({

            /**
             * @inheritDoc
             */
            createPopUp: function (element) {
                this.modalWindow = element;
                var options = {
                    'type': 'popup',
                    'modalClass': 'popup-authentication',
                    'responsive': true,
                    'innerScroll': true,
                    'trigger': '.download-purchase', // only change needed
                    'buttons': []
                };
                //console.log(options);
                modal(options, $(this.modalWindow));
            }
        });
    };
});
```